# Little Endian to Big Endian Precision Error

Tags: java, apache-commons, bytebuffer, endianness

I am writing a program in Java to input a file to be used by an other program written in C++. In consequence, this file must be a little endian binary file of floats.

I have used many different types of ways to make this endian conversion including Apache Commons I/O, the Geosoft utility (which is the exact same thing as apache..), and ByteBuffer.

In summary, I must take a bunch of floats and display them in binary little endian. This process works most of the time. However, in certain cases, there seems to be some precision error in the endian conversion where a float is recognized as NaN. As a result, instead of the specific float, a number like 6.055E-41 or something is displayed when I read the binary file that I have just written about 1% of the time. I have searched for similar problems online.

One other person had diagnosed the error to be contained within the conversion between float to Int Bits and Int Bits to float (found in the Apache and Geosoft Utilities).

The recommended solution was to make the file directly into int bits rather than doing this round about process. However, converting directly into integers, in my case, would make me lose precision on the original floats that I need to write. The recommended solution was, for your reference:

> "By reading a float using the readFloat() routine of DataInputStream, converting it to bits using Float.floatToIntBits(), swapping the Integer, then converting it back to float  using Float.intBitsToFloat() causes a precision error in certain cases resulting in junk  being returned.
>
> The solution is to write a new set of routines that read the bits from the bytestream directly into integers, then perform the byte swapping and converting it back to a float."

Here is an example of the problem...

When writing these series of floats into a binary file and reading them back, the result expected is this:

> 1.50411975
>   -1.974895
>   1.0301249
>   -0.43540177
>   0.8161005
>   0.38000694
>   0.43332508

However, I am seeing this:

> 6.9055E-41
>   -1.974895
>   1.0301249
>   -0.43540177
>   0.8161005
>   0.38000694
>   0.43332508

I am pasting my code. This version specifically uses a byte buffer implementation. Can you please tell me what is wrong and how I can go about fixing it?

```
public int writeBinaryFile( ArrayList<P> p) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException 
{ 
    int c = 0;


    for (int i = 0; i < p(); i++)
    {
        ArrayList<Float> cube = new ArrayList<Float>();
        ArrayList<Float> dir = p.get(i).getDirection();
        ArrayList<Float> pos = p.get(i).getPosition();
        Float angle = (float) p.get(i).getAngle();
        Float id = (float) p.get(i).getPEvents().get(0).getid();
        ArrayList<Float> things = new ArrayList<Float>();
        boolean truism = true;


    if (dir.get(1) > 0 ) {  

        /*byte [] byte2 = this.float2ByteArray(id);
        float f = ByteBuffer.wrap(byte2).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN ).getFloat();
        dos.writeFloat(f);*/

        for (int j = 0; j < pos.size(); j++) {
            byte [] bytes = this.float2ByteArray(pos.get(j));
            float d = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN ).getFloat();
            cube.add(d);
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < dir.size(); j++) {
            byte [] bytes = this.float2ByteArray(dir.get(j));
            float d = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN ).getFloat();
            cube.add(d);
        }

        byte [] bytes = this.float2ByteArray(angle);
        float d = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN ).getFloat();
        cube.add(d);

        if (this.checkCube(cube)) {this.writeCube(cube); c++; }

    }

    }
    return c;
}

    public byte [] float2ByteArray(float value)
{
    return ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putFloat(value).array();
}
```

Here is the alternate swapping mechanism I have:

```
 public static float swap (float value)
  {
    int intValue = Float.floatToRawIntBits (value);
    intValue = swap (intValue);
    return Float.intBitsToFloat (intValue);
  }

 public static int swap (int value)
  {
    int b1 = (value >>  0) & 0xff;
    int b2 = (value >>  8) & 0xff;
    int b3 = (value >> 16) & 0xff;
    int b4 = (value >> 24) & 0xff;
    return b1 << 24 | b2 << 16 | b3 << 8 | b4 << 0;
  }
```

I tried using something that directly uses integers. Here is my special swapper:

```
 public static float specialswap (float value)
 {
     int intValue = Float.floatToRawIntBits (value);
     return Integer.reverseBytes(Integer.parseInt(Integer.toBinaryString(intValue)));
```

### }

Resolved: Thanks to Louis Wasserman, the answer to my problems was found:

```
dataOutputStream.writeInt(Integer.reverseBytes(Float.floatToRawIntBits(float)))‌​.
```

Comment: `Float.floatToIntBits` doesn't cost you any precision at all.  Why do you suggest it would?  (I mean, it'll merge different NaNs, but that shouldn't be an issue for you, and even if it were, you could use `Float.floatToRawIntBits` instead.)

Comment: @Louis I've already tried Float.floatToRawIntBits, and it does not make a difference. As to the first part of the comment, I guess it is not some precision error then. But whatever name is given to categorize the error, the float is recognized as an NaN sequence. I'm not sure how to remedy this. What I meant to say was that converting directly to an Int instead of the roundabout conversion step should definitely cost precision.

Comment: A `float` is 32 bits.  An `int` is 32 bits.  `Float.floatToRawIntBits` and `Float.intBitsToFloat` are perfect inverses; that should be entirely reversible.  Do you have a test that demonstrates the problem more concretely?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not being clear. I agree that using the inverse procedures does not change anything. The problem is that some floats are recognized, in this process, as NaNs. As for precision, I was referring to a suggested solution on another forum to a similar problem. I am adding the person's suggestion to the question itself along with a few test cases.

Comment: @Louis An example of the problem is up. This only occurs about 1% of the time.

Comment: @Louis Also, the anomaly passes the FLOAT.isNan() test, so it is confirmed as a NaN. How do I prevent this NaN recognition sequence from activating when converting the endianness of a float?

Comment: @LouisWasserman I tried RawIntBits again. I was wondering if I was doing it correctly.. I am still not able to take out the NaN values.

Here is what I have: public static float swap (float value)
   {
     int intValue = Float.floatToRawIntBits (value);
     intValue = swap (intValue);
     return Float.intBitsToFloat (intValue);
   }

Comment: Why are you calling `intValue = swap(intValue)`?

Comment: I called it, as that is the line that swaps the bytes.

Comment: Is that a different `swap` method?  You're defining `float swap(float value)` and then calling a different `swap` method?  And does it make sense to cast the endianness-swapped value back to float at all rather than keeping it as an `int`?

Comment: Yes, it's a different swap method that takes an int. I'll post the code in the question. The C++ program that I am inputting the binary file into requires floats, so I thought it necessary to cast back. These methods are similar to those found in the Apache Commons I/O EndianUtils.java file.

Comment: If you write them as `int`s, that should probably still work, if the C++ program is trying to read them in as bytes.  FWIW, the basic JDK has a method to reverse the byte order of an `int`: `Integer.reverseBytes(int)`.

Comment: This is a dumb question, but I'm not exactly sure how to go about doing that..

I tried using a new swapper method that I made (code pasted to question), and I keep getting a numberFormatException. I seriously hope I am not making some stupid error.. Here is a section of the log: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "10111111001000110110010110001110"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)

Comment: Are you getting numbers _from_ the input stream, or writing them _to_ an output stream?  It's _still_ not clear what you're trying to do.  If you're reading them from an `InputStream`, you should just be doing the one line `Float.intBitsToFloat(Integer.reverseBytes(dataInputStream.readInt()))`.  If you're writing them to an `OutputStream`, you should just be doing the one line `dataOutputStream.writeInt(Integer.reverseBytes(Float.floatToRawIntBits(float)))`.  Everything else is just going around in circles.

Comment: I'm doing the latter. Thanks for your help. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Can you post an official answer or something if you want to so I can acknowledge it?

I'm not really sure how to handle this, as I'm new to the site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you getting numbers from the input stream, or writing them to an output stream? It's still not clear what you're trying to do. If you're reading them from an `InputStream`, you should just be doing the one line `Float.intBitsToFloat(Integer.reverseBytes(dataInputStream.readInt()))`. If you're writing them to an `OutputStream`, you should just be doing the one line `dataOutputStream.writeInt(Integer.reverseBytes(Float.floatToRawIntBits(float)))‌`​. Everything else is just going around in circles.